Allowing 2 Deployments access Persistent Disk in Kubernetes
Problem statement:
Designing a system where one Deployment (W) writes data to Persistent Disk (PD) and other Deployment/Daemonset (R) moves data out of the PD. It would be fair to assume this is a pretty high throughput.
I am pretty new to Kubernetes and trying to figure out what would be the best way to handle this. One approach is having something like NFS with RWX attached to the nodes of a cluster. Trying to find non-NFS approach.
Another approach is making W as StatefulSet with volumeClaimTemplates. This will ensure a new PVC coming up for every W pod. I am making sure W would have exactly 1 pod per node using podantiaffinity. So the PVC would be attached to a single node with RWO. I believe this would allow all the pods on that node to access the PVC. Assuming that this is true, now the question comes how can R access this PVC and move the data out?

Does this have to be "files"?  Especially if you're still in the design stage?  Would a streaming messaging system like Kafka meet your needs better?

...or object storage, like an AWS-S3-alike (Minio, Ceph, etc).

@DavidMaze Kafka or some streaming architecture is definitely a better design here. But it is quickly getting costly for us. We want to check if we can do it cost-effectively if possible. If writing to a PD and flushing it out is not even technically possible, then we would go with a streaming solution.

Using StatefulSet is most likely your best bet when it comes to attaching PVCs to pods in a Kubernetes cluster. Although it is not impossible, nor anything will stop you from creating ad-hoc PVC per node and attach them to each pod of a Deployment powered by affinity configurations.
However, using StatefulSet gives you the ability to pin a pod and its volume to a specific node. That will have the advantage of Kubernetes scheduler not moving your pods around too much and while doing so, increasing the time for the pod to boot up because of the CSI driver trying to re-attach the volume to another node.
That said, and although I don't see it in your question, I assume you're trying to backup the contents of those volumes with the pods that will read the contents. If that's the case, you're most likely doing it periodically.
Which might be a good candidate to use Kubernetes CronJob. However, using volumeClaimTemplates won't make it easy to specify which pod of a CronJob should attach which volume. One dirty workaround is to use a CronJob that spins up another Job while determining the volume name. That will, of course, need RBAC and might make the case complicated.
A better and more accessible solution I'm proposing you'd do is to run your StatefulSet pods with a sidecar container next to them. That will have the benefit of each of the containers of a pod having access to the PVC without much coordination and orchestration required. You'd only need to write a couple of lines of scripts of your preferred language to do whatever you want to do with the contents of those volumes.
For your reference, here's a sample example of a StatefulSet. One container of each pod will write data to the PVC while the other, having only readonly access, will back them up to the AWS S3.
Notice the periodic sleep placed on the second container to mimic the behavior of a Kubernetes CronJob.
This solution tends to be less complex than using one CronJob to spin up another Job (which will require Kubernetes RBAC).
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: awesome-app
spec:
  serviceName: awesome-app
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: awesome-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: awesome-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: write
          image: busybox
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              while sleep 60; do
                dd if=/dev/urandom of=/data/$(date +%s) bs=1M count=1
              done
        - name: backup
          image: amazon/aws-cli
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
              readOnly: true
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |
              while sleep 300; do
                aws s3 sync /data s3://my-bucket
              done
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: app
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - awesome-app
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

